# Heroku custom domains

Tags: heroku, ovh

***I'm trying to add a custom domain for my heroku app,  myapp.herokuapp.com to www.example.com***

**Here are the steps i've done so far :**

1. In heroku setting, i added my custom domains, so heroku gave my the
   following DNS Target: www.example.com.herokudns.com
2. On my DNS provider (ovh) setting, i created the following CNAME
   record: www.example.com with the following target:
   www.example.com.herokudns.com
3. I waited for more than 24hours, but i still cant access my site with
   www.example.com

Did i forget one step ?

Many thanks

Comment: is the domain actually registered with ovh? otherwise you'll have to additionally tell your NIC which DNS to use. 

What's the output of `whois www.yourdomain.com`? (there you'll see which DNS is used for that domain)

What's the output of `dig www.yourdomain.com`? (there you'll see if the CNAME is set and available). 

A change to the WHOIS can take up to two days to propagate everywhere, the change to the DNS depends on the TTL (caching-time) you defined)